# Macro to save password protected file

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I wrote the following macro in Excel2010 for an action button to save a given sheet as password protected file on a shared drive.

```
Private Sub Report_Click()

 Sheets("sheetname").SaveAs Filename:="\\shared_folder_path\master" & Sheets("sheetname").Range("A2"), _
                            FileFormat:=52, _
                            Password:="password", _
                            WriteResPassword:="password", _
                            ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
                            CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

The problem is that I get a Run-time error '1004'

Comment: I can never understand why it wouldn't be important to know what was in `Range("A2")`. I'm guessing that it is a date and as such, contains characters like the forward slash that are either illegal in a filename or confusing the destination folder structure. If you have a date in A2 and you've formatted the cell so that it can be used as part of a filename then use `.Range("A2").Text`. Of course, if that were the case, you would have seen a large [error message popup](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vBN8f.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it has something to do with your `FileName` path.

I tested it and just used a path this links to my desktop and it saved fine. Try the same test replacing the path with a path to your desktop.

You will need to add the assigned Drive letter your computer uses to the network folder path possibly.

A cleaner way of presenting the same code is below with the

```
 Private Sub Report_Click()
      Sheets("Sheet1").SaveAs _
           Filename:="C:\Users\user1\Desktop\" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2"), _
           FileFormat:=52, _
           Password:="password", _
           WriteResPassword:="password", _
           ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
           CreateBackup:=False
 End Sub
```

Also have a look at this [How to programmatically save a file to a network drive in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/kb/213641) for a basic example.

Comment: Indeed it was an issue with the path: cell A2 contained a : which made the path invalid. Removing the : solved the issue.